# Loop an json array object using JavaScript in Pentaho

Tags: javascript, json, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have this json format data:

```
"records":[
 {
   "status":"active",
   "version":5,
   "assigned_to":null,
   "form_values":
     {
       "lastName":"Doe",
       "photos":
         [
         {
          "photo_id":"ahfhghea08-c938-4ea7",
          "caption":null
         },
         {
          "photo_id":"38ffgh847d-0ced-4425",
          "caption":null
         },
         {
          "photo_id":"7hgj6a264-cba7-4165",
          "caption":null
         }

         ]
    },

      "status":"active",
      "version":1,
      "assigned_to":null,
      "form_values":
     {
       "lastName":"James",
       "photos":
         [
         {
          "photo_id":"ahfhghea08-c938-4ea7",
          "caption":null
         }

        ]
    }
 }
]
```

I'm trying to loop through the photos array and append only photo_id without caption separated by %.

The output should be like this: 
https://web.photos.com/photos/view?photos=ahfhghea08-c938-4ea7%38ffgh847d-0ced-4425%7hgj6a264-cba7-4165

I'm able to display it with only one photo_id and this is the output I get: https://web.photos.com/photos/view?photos=ahfhghea08-c938-4ea7

when I try to append the second photo_id, I get this error "cannot read property photo_id from undefined". because sometimes there is only 1 photo_id and not multiple photo_id.

I'm writing the script using Javascript in Pentaho.

**Update:**

This is the json input:

```
{"records":[{"status":"checked","version":5,"id":"bfc72756d-c819-4641-94a5-9ddd556345b","updated_at":"2019-11-25T16:07:46Z","client_created_at":"2019-11-25T14:38:43Z","client_updated_at":"2019-11-25T16:07:42Z","created_by":"Officer","created_by_id":"1ce0f34c-261b-437d-85d9-f79dda6be9d5","updated_by":"jOHN DOE","updated_by_id":"22d0da53-f153-4fdf-a009-8f2c9c0f8259","created_location":{"latitude":40.8159545,"longitude":-73.925375,"altitude":-30.1000003814697,"horizontal_accuracy":30.166},"updated_location":{"latitude":40.81592,"longitude":-73.9261654,"altitude":-23.7999992370605,"horizontal_accuracy":21.783},"created_duration":199,"updated_duration":1232,"edited_duration":2812,"form_id":"5ea14632-93ed-479c-afcb-3b94e163fc6f","project_id":null,"assigned_to":null,"assigned_to_id":null,"form_values":{"3aee":"MWF","c6da":{"other_values":[],"choice_values":["Supervisor"]},"117e":"2019-11-25","48bf":"Park","2e24":"Michael","ada7":"Doe","96cd":"no","931f":{"sub_thoroughfare":"213","thoroughfare":"Street","suite":null,"locality":null,"sub_admin_area":"Bronx County","admin_area":"","postal_code":"","country":""},"4755":"24","ffff":{"other_values":[],"choice_values":[""]},"a3e8":"9292140202","db5e":"10:30","d657":"09:38","6faa":"Michael dOE","dbcf":"2019-11-25","05b9":"Canal","69a7":"no","2738":"","3085":"","92fe":"2019-1484","8e8b":"no","40da":"","a804":"Street","dc96":[{"photo_id":"08b16f6b-68f0-45d2-b77c-87654059db6","caption":null},{"photo_id":"1d0569af1-2780-4a87-9e56-7e8c149604ac","caption":null},{"photo_id":"39868f21-1056-54fce-8c27-1e86991c4c11","caption":null}],"5d7d":"","f849":{"other_values":[],"choice_values":[""]},"eeb8":{"other_values":[],"choice_values":["In Street","On Sidewalk","Tree Pit"]},"c82d":"","b775":"","9b11":{"choice_values":["VIA Email Group","VIA Telephone"],"other_values":[]},"cc8e":"no","2135":{"choice_values":[""],"other_values":[]},"e537":"no","42d6":"yes","049f":"","15ae":"4554","c9e2":"47","photos":[{"photo_id":"abd56a08-c858-4ea7-989f-907a9*3241a93d","caption":null}],"1be6":"11:06","42ef":{"signature_id":"42c73-d075-45cb-a3bc-e7bdd1b4","timestamp":"2019-11-25T16:06:25Z"}},"latitude":40.8159545,"longitude":-73.925375,"altitude":-30.1000003814697,"speed":null,"course":289.8938,"horizontal_accuracy":30.166,"vertical_accuracy":null},{"status":"checked","version":4,"id":"a48c6ea-9f9b-4c89-9246-65468","created_at":"2019-11-26T15:33:23Z","updated_at":"2019-11-27T16:08:18Z","client_created_at":"2019-11-26T15:08:28Z","client_updated_at":"2019-11-27T16:08:18Z","created_by":"Jessie","created_by_id":"2a53-f153-4fdf-a009-8f2c8259","updated_by":"John","created_location":{"latitude":40.8164889,"longitude":-73.8912291,"altitude":-14.4613952637,"horizontal_accuracy":8.576},"updated_location":{"latitude":40.8392644,"horizontal_accuracy":5.984},"created_duration":1240,"updated_duration":90,"edited_duration":2639,"form_id":"5e32-93ed-479c-afcb-3b556fc6f","form_values":{"92fe":"2019-1494","5d7d":"","049f":"","42ef":{"signature_id":"82d-5ff-4e74-865e-af4a96547fbd9","timestamp":"2019-11-26T15:30:38.000Z"},"42d6":"yes","a3e8":"3478890138","05b9":"","6faa":"","3085":"","8e8b":"no","c9e2":"2","dbcf":"2019-11-26","48bf":"","1be6":"10:29","a804":"","eeb8":{"choice_values":["In Street"],"other_values":[]},"d657":"09:55","c6da":{"choice_values":[],"other_values":["Supervisor "]},"15ae":"4040","69a7":"no","db5e":"10:08","40da":"BX02","cc8e":"no","96cd":"no","photos":[{"photo_id":"918564fa9-eacc-585b9b-aa3e-a09637b1188","caption":null}],"2e24":"David","ffff":{"choice_values":[""],"other_values":[]},"dc96":[{"photo_id":"19145590-beb5-461e-bac2-6f45546af1a","caption":null}],"ada7":"","931f":{"country":"","sub_admin_area":"B","suite":null,"admin_area":"","locality":null,"postal_code":"","thoroughfare":"","sub_thoroughfare":"1231"},"2135":{"choice_values":[""],"other_values":[]},"3aee":"MWF","f849":{"choice_values":[""],"other_values":[]},"117e":"2019-11-26","e537":"no","4755":"2","2738":"","5d37":"Hazlog # 2019-1493","c82d":"","b775":"","9b11":{"choice_values":[],"other_values":[""]}},"latitude":40.8164889,"longitude":-73.8912291,"altitude":-14.4613952637,"speed":null,"course":318.7767,"horizontal_accuracy":8.576,"vertical_accuracy":null}]}
```

I am trying to get the value of photo_id in photos attribute. This one: `"photos":[{"photo_id":"918564fa9-eacc-585b9b-aa3e-a09637b1188","caption":null}]`

As you can see in the json input, sometimes the photos array can contain only one photo_id value and sometimes it can contain more than one. When multiple photo_id values are availablE, I need to concatenate the values in this format: `https://web.photos.com/photos/view?photos=(1st photo_id value)%(2nd photo_id value)%....`

I am able to read the value of the 1st photo_id this way: `['photos'])[0] ['photo_id']` but when the 2nd photo_id value is not provided I get undefined and the script broke.

How can I check if the 2nd photo_id is provided then concatenate it to the url string?

Comment: Both links you put are showing 404 errors.

Comment: First off, if this is your input, it isn't working because this is a not JSON formatted String. Could you post the correct JSON. Also, Don't use JScript Steps in Pentaho unless absolutely necessary, use JSON Input step cascaded several times, you have an example of this usage in your samples folder ..\\data-integration\samples\transformations\JSON - read nested fields.ktr

Comment: @CristianCurti the input is a very long json I tried to share only the section that it's in question. I have to use JScript as a team agreement from the organization team to work with Pentaho.

Comment: @nsousa the links are cut off so it doesn't show the pictures as a security purpose because these pictures are related to the organization

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu I'm not looping the array I'm just displaying the first item in the array this way var photo_url = photos [0] ['photo_id']

Comment: @ITDeveloper do you still have the issue

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu unfortunately I still do

Comment: @ITDeveloper, the two photos you showed are not opening. Could you post the expected output and the code you tried?

Comment: also post entire json

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu The expected output is to have a url with all photos separated by %. i.e: https://web.photos.com/photos/view?photos=ahfhghea08-c938-4ea7%2C7486a264-cba7-4165-8b5c%a6ed47c2-c8aa-42d1-9c32
In this url there 3 photos are there are 3 of %
I can't post the right url or json because the they are confidential to the organization. I tried to post part of the json in question with the photos elements.

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu I added the full input json and what I did and what the expected result is. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CristianCurti  I added the full input json and what I did and what the expected result is. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found this resource that i think might be of help - [link](https://community.hitachivantara.com/s/question/0D51J00004fdU93/jsonparse-doesnt-work-in-javascript-step)

Comment: @CristianCurti Thank you for sharing the link. I was able to loop through the array of photos and able to see the values in the alert using this: var photos = [
{"photo_id":"abd08-c938-4ea7-949f-907c1a93d","caption":null},
{"photo_id":"38f47d-0ced-4425-8b81-cfaaaf14a","caption":null},
{"photo_id":"4ff4c-30d2-4ce2-9d55-d841394473","caption":null}]

for (var key in photos) {
       if (photos.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          alert(photos[key].photo_id); 
       }
    }
However,only the last photo_id value is saved. How can I concatenate all the photo_id values and separate them with %?

Comment: @CristianCurti I used the suggestion from the link that you mentioned but it didn't work for me